# Ideal way of informing team about teammates resignation?

Tags: communication

**Summary/Question**

Ideal way of informing team about teammates resignation?

**Description**

People leave organization for better prospects and other reasons. I want to know,

- what is a **correct way** of informing the team of their resignations and
- what is the **correct time** to inform teammates?

What is a **correct way** ?

- Should we just share an email about the person leaving?
- Should we call for a meeting and inform the team?
- Should we just don’t do anything and slowly let the news come out of its own?

what is the **correct time**? Please note that we have 90 days notice period

- Should we inform the team about the resignation when as a Manager I have a clarity that he/she is not ready to reconsider? *Has a risk of too much of talk and people getting influenced by the person who is about to leave.*
- Should inform well in advance? *Risk is same as above.*
- Should inform maybe a week or two early? *To avoid negativity or unwanted discussions.*

I am looking for your experiences with your organization or what process you like personally? I might agree that action might be different based on situation but in general, what you feel worked for you or your organization? Some ideal practices maybe!

Comment: There are so many considerations--likely too many--to derive an ideal solution. You need to consider the rank of the departing person, maturity of the team, whether there is negativity or low morale present, risk of sabotage, turnover rate, etc.

Comment: Agreed @DavidEspina. Defining those and then discussing will be a big task so just trying to understand in general.

Comment: This is a workplace question that has little to do with project management. But we seem to have no migration path to Workplace.SE, so...

Comment: @nvoigt If you don't see a migration option nested under flags, bring this up in meta. However, I agree with your assessment, and am migrating it to Workplace SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Work out a transition plan. Figure out what needs to get documented, what roles, responsibilities, and task need to transferred and who needs to be involved.
2. Tell the people involved when they actually need to know.
3. General announcement about one week before departure. "Alice has decided to pursue other opportunities, we wish her well for her future"

Answer (score 3):

Given that it is highly unlikely that your employee has signed a gag order not to speak about their status, it isn't really your choice. If they want to talk, they'll talk.

Ask your employee what they prefer. Try to work out a plan that you are both happy with. Make sure the team hears from their manager or better yet the person who quits in an official meeting (for example your next daily standup, weekly status meeting or whatever else you have). The worst thing is gossip in the hallway. If you can make an official announcement, with the employee present or even with the employee making that anouncement themselves, that would be best.

Answer (score 3):

There best way to let everybody know: whatever way works for the situation.

I have know people who are retiring to let management and coworkers know a year in advance. I have experienced a situation where nobody other than management knew until the day after their last day because the employee didn't want anybody to know.

The delay between informing management and the rest of the team should be worked out right after the manager/company is notified.

I as the departing employee would never want to have a formal announcement in an official meeting, because I would have nothing to say except my last day is X. As a manager I would not want to put the employee into that spot. But I am sure that in some situations that could be the best approach.

Sometimes there is a slight delay to consider the short term impacts, so that at the same time the word gets out there is already a plan for who will be trained or who will have to be reassigned. If there is a key customer that has to be informed management will likely handle that notification, because the customer will want to know the impact and the plan.

Know that you will never control the full chain of notification. Once the word gets  out it will spread.

Answer (score 1):

**Has a risk of too much of talk and people getting influenced by the person who is about to leave.**

Ummm... OK. If you're worried about this then what does that say about the company and you as a manager? Other employees won't be influenced by a person who's leaving if they themselves are happy. Maybe you have bigger problems to address?

As for the crux of your question, I personally would announce the resignation as soon as possible. If there are regular "all hands" meetings I'd announce it at the next one, if not then I'd send an email. Their need be no political intrigue or drama.

Comment: people get influenced by the gossip that gets initiated by the person leaving EVEN if they are happy with their job. Either way, people themselves find a way to be “Unhappy” when they compare themselves with others. However I agree with second half of your post and agree that announcement asap will be a better.